# Slideable PopUp dialogue in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have been using this package [slide_popup_dialog](https://pub.dev/packages/slide_popup_dialog) but this package have not get updated with flutter 2 and null safety.
is there any way so i can use this package still with flutter 2 or is there any other package to do this too?

Comment: Convert package to null safety using dart tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see a non null-safety package, open the [Github](https://github.com/dhimasdewanto/slide_popup_dialog) page and go to [Forks](https://github.com/dhimasdewanto/slide_popup_dialog/network/members), you'll find some people that updated. [Using package from Github](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages)

**Example:**

Add the following code to your `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
dependencies:
  slide_popup_dialog:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/kw2019ltd/slide_popup_dialog.git
      ref: main
```

This github fork it's the `slide_popup_dialog` updated to null-safety.

Answer (score 1):

[You don't need packages to do so](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App',
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
          isScrollControlled: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.white,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 200.0,
                child: Text('PopUp'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: Text('Show PopUp'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```